# Is this a good way to debounce a switch?

Tags: transistors, switches, debounce

There are plenty of debouncing circuits on the internet, but I couldn't really find one that fitted my needs / available parts, so I came up with my own, from what I had. There's nothing special about it, and it probably already exists, I just haven't come across it yet.

Here's the schematic:

[schematic http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141017/debouncing_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141017/debouncing_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

I guess it works with 5V as well, but I use this with my Raspberry Pi, which has 3.3V logic on the GPIO pins, that's why it says that on the schematic.

I went with the 330k and 100nF combo because I read that some switches can even have a 10+ ms bounce, so I really wanted to make sure this thing smoothes out everything. I don't need super fast switching, so this is fine for me. It makes both rising and falling edges very smooth. Also, it kind of inverts the switch: when it's open, the output reads high, and when you close it, it drops to 0V. But I'm good with that.

So I just wanted to know whether this is any good, or should I take a different approach? What do you think of it? Any advice maybe?

## EDIT:

I updated the circuit a bit based on your suggestions. I realized that the 220 ohm resistors were wasting current for nothing, so I replaced them with more appropriate values. Also, I went with 100k / 150nF for faster operation. I think that the 330k / 100nF was a bit of an overkill. As you can see, that would reach 1.8V (roughly the logic threshold for the Raspberry Pi GPIOs) in about [25ms](http://mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php?vfrom=0.0&vto=3.3&vs=3.3&c=100n&r=330k&time=0.1). This new circuit takes about [10ms](http://mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php?vfrom=0.0&vto=3.3&vs=3.3&c=150n&r=100k&time=0.1) to reach that level, therefore allowing over 10ms of bouncing, which is enough for almost all switches, and still unnoticeable for a human.

Also, I know that I the transistor is redundant, but I already built it this way, so I'm leaving it in there.

[schematic 2 http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141018/debouncing_v2_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141018/debouncing_v2_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it on the Raspberry Pi? For example you could just ignore a second transition if it occurs within 100ms of the first.

Comment: That's software debouncing. Sure, I could do that, but that's not the point here. I want to do it in hardware, that's it. Also, I might need hardware debouncing for other projects in the future, where software debouncing cannot be done. It would be useful if I have a working circuit then, so why not do it if I have time now?

Comment: you certainly do not need a transistor! Just a resistor or two and a capacitor is all you need. switches do not have a constant 10ms bounce period, they are completely up to the contacts of the switch, the way it's pressed, the type of swith, and other factors. They could be 1ms or 0.1ms bouncing, I doubt 10ms is normal, perhaps you found that to be a 'safe enough for all cases' and surely good enough response time for human input.

Comment: I wrote some sturdy software debounce code a while ago, and found that the small surface mount tactile switches (which get used for almost everything) tend to bounce for up to 8ms, so immunity to 10 - 20ms of bouncing sounds like a good idea. But as you said, it varies. Hookup a scope and take a looksie.

Comment: This circuit does not really debounce- it is just a low pass filter (well, with some gain when you have the transistor), so it depends on the input to the micro having enough hysteresis to overcome the most pathological bounce scenario. It's probably not well guaranteed, but probably good enough.

Answer (score 9):

In your design, assuming you're using a common small signal NPN BJT (2n2222, BC547, 2n3904…), you're wasting about 20-30mA of current when the switch is closed. That is, about 10-15mA through the upper 220Ω resistor and 10-15 through the lower one.
In addition, driving the base of the transistor with 10mA or more in this situation makes no sense: using a 10KΩ base resistor and thus reducing base current makes the circuit behave almost in the same way.
That said, I would just avoid using the transistor, something like this should work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxbBUC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I kept your values for R1 and C1, so the cutoff frequency of the circuit is similar to yours. I.e., the GPIO pin will not 'see' changes of the switch above about 5Hz (well, *simplistic* and not completely exact: see [Wikipedia - Low Pass Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Passive_electronic_realization) for detailed info).

R2 is used as pull-down resistor: it is useful because it clearly *pulls* the pin to ground when the switch is open. Its value isn't critical, something between 10 and 150KΩ should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, yes.

Long answer, yes and use a circuit simulator!

Green trace is the switch, blue is the debounced output.

[image]

Comment: I used one, but that one's pretty basic. This looks promising

Comment: I used LTSpice, its free from the Linear Tech website.

Answer (score 3):

So when you press the switch You turn On the transistor and when you release the transistor is cut-off.
So why use transistor in first place can't you just connect your switch instead of transistor.?
I mean Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9KGiq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Don't care about component Values)

Comment: You're right, the transistor is actually redundant. I'm going to keep it in there anyway, since I already built the circuit.